# Formatting bug when newline is present in chat message

Tags: bug, chat, markdown

I recently noticed that when there are new-lines in the same chat message, Markdown support fails.  For example:

```
*Test* 

**TEST**
```

This **won't** produce the expected output:

> *Test*
>
> **TEST**

It leaves the message as it is with the Markdown text included. [Here's proof](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1735081#1735081) if needed.  Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: So, is this worth fixing?

Comment: Reproed in the sandbox on meta as well. Markdown doesn't work if a new line is present in the message using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is it that hard to fix?

Comment: Don't know.  I'm not an SE developer. :)  I'm just wondering how often someone might actually need this.

Comment: Could be that it is by design because if I hit shift+enter I see on the right of the message box a button 'fixed font' appear.

Comment: @rene: No, that just gives you the option to convert to fixed font.  Multiple newlines suggests code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmmm, in that case  I'm out of options. I doubt it is a user error.

Comment: @hichris123 Hmmm, didn't see that when searching to make sure this wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: @syb0rg I assure you I didn't fabricate that question out of thin air just so I could mark it a duplicate. :P

Comment: @hichris123 I know.  It's just usually people don't do the required research before asking a proper question.  I thought I did in this case.  Whoops ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's by design: that something with newline is interpreted as a source code block.

Having a newline also lets that post avoid the maximum-message-length limit.

Comment: But it doesn't look like it is formatting it as a code either.

Comment: @syb0rg once your message has multiple lines, a "fixed font" button is offered for the desired effect. But I do think the current behavior is confusing.